# How to assign probability according to mathematical expectation

Tags: python, algorithm

## Abstract

```
p1 * cost1 + p2 * cost2 + p3 * cost3 + ... = n
p1 + p2 + p3 + ... = 1
```

#### Known

cost1, cost2, cost3, ...

n

#### Solve

p1, p2, p3, ...

## Description

I'm going to make a card-picking game (amuse myself). Now I have many cards with different cost, such as:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'card1',
        'cost': 10
    },
    {
        'name': 'card2',
        'cost': 100
    },
    {
        'name': 'card3',
        'cost': 1000
    },
    {
        'name': 'card4',
        'cost': 10000
    },
]
```

Then I want the mathematical expectation of this game equals to `500`. So I have an idea that divide mathematical expectations into different parts, then  calculate their probabilities separately.

```
[
    {
        'name': 'card1',
        'cost': 10,
        'math_expect': 3,
    },
    {
        'name': 'card2',
        'cost': 100,
        'math_expect': 30,
    },
    {
        'name': 'card3',
        'cost': 1000,
        'math_expect': 300,
    },
    {
        'name': 'card4',
        'cost': 10000,
        'math_expect': 167,
    },
]
```

Now I can get probabilities for each card.

```
p_card1 = 3 / 10  # 0.3
p_card2 = 30 / 100  # 0.3
p_card3 = 300 / 1000  # 0.3
p_card4 = 167 / 10000  # 0.0167
p_sum = p_card1 + p_card2 + p_card3 + p_card4  # 0.9167
```

As you can see, the probability sum does not equal to 1, so I must assign a new probability `p_no_card = 1 - p_sum = 0.0833`. In fact, if I change the expectations distribution, the probability sum is even greater than 1.

So I wrote a fool nested loop to do that:

```
cost1 = 10
cost2 = 100
cost3 = 1000
cost4 = 10000

for i in range(cost1):
    for j in range(min(cost2, 500 - i)):
        for k in range(min(cost3, 500 - i - j)):
            l = 500 - i - j - k
            p_sum = 1.0 * i / cost1 + 1.0 * j / cost2 + 1.0 * k / cost3 + 1.0 * l / cost4
            if abs(p_sum - 1) < 0.0005:
                print p_sum, i, j, k, l
```

Through this nested loop, I can get many results and choose a best option for my game. But if I want to add more card, for example, 100 cards, this loop will become to slower and imprecise (easy to understand, if each part of expectation is too small, range step `1` will be too big).

So how can I assign mathematical expectations quickly and accurately? One idea is enough. I can implement the corresponding code myself.

Comment: I think you're overthinking it and mixing up the cost with your card probabilities.When you set the `math_expect` values, that's already the distribution itself - normalized against a value of 500. You should use the denominator of 500 to calculate its 100-based probability, instead of the cost value. E.g. Card 3 would have a probability of 60 %: `300/500`

Comment: @kerwei Does it mean card 4 have a probability `10000/500`? I think it is not correct.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You shouldn't mix up your cost with the probability distribution of your card being drawn, which you set through the `math_expect` values. Therefore, the probability should be `167/500` or 33.4%. Why do you want to bring the cost into the equation though?

Comment: @kerwei Sorry, I don't know very well between these similar words such as `price`, `cost` or `worth`. I mean if a player picked this card, he will gained how much money.

Comment: You want to solve for `p1 * cost1 + p2 * cost2 + ... = 500` while ensuring that all probabilities are positive and sum to one. There are infinitely many solutions. One way to do this is to start by assigning uniform probabilities and then changing them to get closer to your desired expected value (e.g. through gradient descent).

Comment: _if a player picked this card, he will gain how much money_. I think the misunderstanding lies here. If a player picks card4, the cost will always be 10000 and nothing else. You should probably frame it as _if a player picks a card, how much money will he gain_. In this case, your distribution remains the same - the values that you have set for the `math_expect` variable i.e. 60% chance of drawing a card of cost 10000 and the average expectation is computed by `math_expect` * `cost` for each of the card

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have no experience with gradient descent. Can it calculate the result quickly? I'm reading some introduction documents now.

Comment: @kerwei Do you mean I assign probability first, then use probability and expectation to calculate cost?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. If you simplify it to a game of just 3 cards then it's easier to visualize. E.g. 2 cards with a value of 5 and 1 card with a value of 10. At the start, the value of the game is valued at `0.66 * 5 + 0.33 * 10` or 6.6. Here, the `math_expect` variables are 2 and 1 respectively. Assuming that the player draws a card of value 5 and the deck does not get replenished/reset, the value of the second round is now `0.5 * 5 + 0.5 * 10` or 7.5 and your `math_expect` variable becomes 1 and 1 (card valued 5 was drawn in round 1 and now there's only 1 left)

Comment: @kerwei Thanks! I will consider about this idea.

Comment: What are the expectations based on? The number of repeated cards?